# SharePoint duplicate file in current directory

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

SharePoint (O365), using the website:
Is there a way to copy a file in the directory that you are currently in?

Now I do:

1. select the file
2. *Copy to*
3. *Current Library*
4. I now have to navigate to the correct directory... (<-- trying to avoid this!!)
5. *Copy here*
6. Select the new file
7. Rename the file

The 'problem' is that Current Library starts at the root each time, so I have to browse and select the correct folder again in order to duplicate a file in that folder.

Comment: +1 upvote. how infuriating that it does it in this in this way! Here's [my answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/298728/101022) to compliment the other existing answer(s). My answer is another, separate, standalone, way to do it if you are not able to use the other answer(s). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a way to do it by opening the original and doing a 'Save as'**

1 - Click on the three vertical dots to the right of your document filename.

2 - The pop up menu is then shown, hover on 'Open'.

3 - A new menu appears, with option 'Open in browser' - click it.

These above 3 steps illustrated in this screenshot:

[image: Getting to 'Open in browser' -> Click on three dots -> Open -> Open In Browser]

4 - Your document will open in a new tab.

5 - Find the File menu link at the top left, as shown in below illustration. It's the option to the left of 'Home':

[image: File menu link at top left on open document]

6 - Click that File menu link to reveal the drop down menu
[image: File menu drop-down options]

7 - Select 'Save as'

8 - a modal dialog/pop over appears - and you can see that it offers to save a copy of your file **in the same place as your original!** Happy days! The copy has a new suggested file name - appended word 'Copy'.

9 - Leave as the suggested offer of location as is - i.e. the same place as the original, and click 'Save'

[image: modal dialog for Save as]

10 - Now go back to your browser tab that had the sharepoint browser that shows your files, including the original. Reload this browser tab, to see the new file listed.

11 - Observe that the copy of the original file now listed! Screenshot below shows this:

[image: new copy now listed]

Above steps done on:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64bit Dell laptop
- In Google Chrome browser
- Logged into Sharepoint via the web, using the Google Chrome browser

(neither the OS or web browser stated above is a Microsoft product, so no dependency on an particular proprietary browser extension, for example. Therefore I would like to be confident that this would work on any other modern web/OS combination, e.g. Edge and W10/W11 for example.)

**Thoughts, non essential - only if interested!**

Much as I love Microsoft (as well as Apple, Google and Linux) and many great things they are doing, I'm sure I'm not the only one who thinks that this is a glaring omission to not just have a menu option 'Make a copy' like Google Drive does. But at least there is another way to do it without too much pain, albeit a few extra steps as I have stated above.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could use "View in File Explorer" feature, then copy the files in the current folder.

[image]

Comment: this doesn't work in Edge, only in Internet Explorer... We don't use that old IE anymore.